# passing argument from python to subprocess.popen

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have this code:

```
from subprocess import Popen
link="abc"
theproc = Popen([sys.executable, "p1.py",link])
```

I want to send the variable "link" to p1.py,
and p1.py will print it.

something like this. here is p1.py:

```
print "in p1.py link is "+ link
```

How can I do that?

Comment: print "in p1.py link is "+ link - this is p1.py

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `python` refers to Python 2.x on your system.

Retrieve the command line argument in `p1.py` using `sys.argv`:

```
import sys

if not len(sys.argv) > 1:
    print "Expecting link argument."
else:
    print "in p1.py link is " + sys.argv[1]
```

There's a function `subprocess.check_output` that is easier to use if you only want to call a program and retrieve its output:

```
from subprocess import check_output

output = check_output(["python", "p1.py", "SOME_URL"])
print "p1.py returned the following output:\n'{}'".format(output)
```

Example output:

```
$ python call_p1.py
p1.py returned the following output:
'in p1.py link is SOME_URL
'
```

Comment: if I want send 2 args' how can I do that?

Comment: Just add more elements to the list passed to `check_output`. As for retrieving them in `p1.py`, `sys.argv` is a list containing the name the program was started as and its arguments, so `sys.argv[1]` is the first argument, `sys.argv[2]` the second and so on.

Comment: @shirastenmetz Please accept my answer if you're satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the command line arguments in your `p1.py` to get it in a variable:

```
import sys
try:
    link = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print 'argument missing'
    sys.exit(1)
```